# “List of devices attached” is empty on Ubuntu 16.04 using "adb devices"

Tags: android, adb

I am unable connect my Android to Ubuntu.

On executing command `lsusb`. It shows attached device.

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:0061 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 025: ID 2a70:9011  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And I have created rule using this command.

```
echo SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2a70", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" | sudo tee /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android-usb.rules
```

And after running  `adb devices`. It is not showing any attached device.

I have also reinstalled adb tools. Even though it is not working.

Answer (score 8):

First, try unplug then plug the device. Then check the the message log using dmesg instead lsusb, because it gives you more information about the idVendor and idProduct. Use the following command to show the last 10 message log:

```
dmesg | tail
```

Now, you can ge the idVendor and idProduct. It will be something like this:

```
[24936.555273] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 9
[24939.022181] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[24939.187152] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
[24939.187154] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[24939.187156] usb 1-2: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
[24939.187157] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[24939.187158] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 5ae1b464
[24939.188132] cdc_acm 1-2:1.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

add the following line to your **/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules** (Beware, you need to change `idVendor`, `idProduct` and `username` to yours):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2a70", ATTR{idProduct}=="9011", MODE="0600", OWNER="username"
```

You also can use the **51-android.rules** file from [android-udev-rules](https://github.com/M0Rf30/android-udev-rules).

Here I'm copying the [step for Ubuntu](https://github.com/M0Rf30/android-udev-rules#ubuntu) from its documentation:

```
# Clone this repository
git clone git@github.com:M0Rf30/android-udev-rules.git
# Create a sym-link to the rules file
sudo cp android-udev-rules/51-android.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/
# Change file permissions
sudo chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
# add the adbusers group if it's doesn't already exist
sudo groupadd adbusers
# Add your user to the adbusers group
sudo usermod -a -G adbusers $(whoami)
# Restart UDEV
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
sudo service udev restart
# Restart the ADB server
adb kill-server
# Replug your Android device and verify that USB debugging is enabled in developer options
adb devices
# You should now see your device
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to enable USB debugging on your phone.

[This video](https://youtu.be/IYWEwQnobkQ?t=33s) demonstrates this from 0:33 to 1:03.

Copying the steps here:

> 1. On your android device, go to `Settings`→`System`→`About phone`. Scroll down to `Build number` and continuously tap on it for a few
>      times until a popup announcing Developer options to have been
>      activated appears.
> 2. Go to `Settings`→`Developer options`→`Debugging` and activate `USB debugging`.

The device should now be listed under `$ adb devices` once connected.

---

*Tested with Android 5.1 and Ubuntu 17.10.*

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with an empty list of `adb devices`. The only solution that worked for me was to take the first part of the device's ID(vendor id `0e8d`):

```
# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 055: ID 0e8d:201d MediaTek Inc.
```

Then edit, or create if it doesn’t exist the file ~/.android/adb_usb.ini and place on a single line the prefix `0x` followed by your vendor id:

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
0x0e8d
```

Then restart the adb:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server;
adb devices
```

Comment: `Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32` is the one that I use and this was the only solution, that helped. How can that possibly be?

Comment: 1.0.32 is **very** old. You should upgrade your `adb`

Comment: Ok, so that is why. That is the version that was installed with the `apt` is the package there outdated or I did something wrong?

Comment: This is the reason why installing `adb` from your linux distribution repository is not recommended. If you want to develop for Android - just use the version which comes with Android SDK

Comment: I just needed to change the resolution of a device, however, I will leave my answer in case someone runs into this. Thank you for the information!

Comment: `adb` can be installed separately from the SDK https://stackoverflow.com/tags/adb/info

Answer (score 2):

Try to switch from MTP mode to PTP mode on your phone, it worked for me.

(got this tip from : https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/101933/samsung-galaxy-s4-does-not-show-authorize-usb-debugging-dialog-box)