# Ubuntu 16.04 adb device list empty

Tags: android, adb, ubuntu-16.04, nokia, android-8.0-oreo

I have the same problem like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46128913/list-of-devices-attached-is-empty-on-ubuntu-16-04-using-adb-devices) (I try to do that explain for help him but it's doesn't work for me) with Nokia 6.1 (on android 8.1), when execute adb devices the list of devices is empty, I do that :

```
sudo apt install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot

adb version ==> Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32

cd /etc/udev/rules.d/

sudo nano 51-android.rules 

sudo chmod a+r 51-android.rules 

sudo groupadd adbusers

sudo usermod -a -G adbusers $(whoami)

sudo udevadm control --reload-rules

sudo service udev restart

adb kill-server

adb devices
```

My 51-android.rules :

```
# These rules refer: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html
# and include many suggestions from Arch Linux, GitHub and other Communities.
# Latest version can be found at: https://github.com/M0Rf30/android-udev-rules

# Skip this section below if this device is not connected by USB
SUBSYSTEM!="usb", GOTO="android_usb_rules_end"

LABEL="android_usb_rules_begin"
# Devices listed here in android_usb_rules_{begin...end} are connected by USB

# Nokia 6
ATTR{idVendor}=="2e04", ENV{adb_user}="yes"

# Symlink shortcuts to reduce code in tests above
ENV{adb_adbfast}=="yes", ENV{adb_adb}="yes", ENV{adb_fast}="yes"
ENV{adb_adb}=="yes", ENV{adb_user}="yes", SYMLINK+="android_adb"
ENV{adb_fast}=="yes", ENV{adb_user}="yes", SYMLINK+="android_fastboot"

Anyone have an idea, what is the problem ? (because I looking for on different forum and I don't know why my list of device is empty)
```

Comment: If I was your place, I ask my question in [Ubuntu Ask Center](https://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: Ok i do that to see