# adb "list of devices attached" empty for USB connection on remote Debian virtual machine

Tags: android, adb, digital-ocean

Running `adb devices` returns an empty list on my DigitalOcean Debian 9 virtual machine. My LG ThinQ 7 running Android is attached by USB to my computer (Mac), and it has debugging turned on in Developer Tools.

I have run adb kill-server and adb start-server, and have unplugged and reattached my phone through USB, making sure that it is unlocked. Running `dmesg | tail` as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46128913/list-of-devices-attached-is-empty-on-ubuntu-16-04-using-adb-devices) results in:

```
[  877.657343] systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 7h 50min 49.113541s random time.
[  877.862296] systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.timer: Adding 30min 45.124112s random time.
[  877.866425] systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 11h 2min 53.916371s random time.
[163405.503232] systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.timer: Adding 11min 3.021099s random time.
[163405.512103] systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 7h 50min 56.568643s random time.
[163410.730443] systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.timer: Adding 9min 26.327309s random time.
[163410.735693] systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 14min 54.237795s random time.
[163410.964357] systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.timer: Adding 33min 39.079893s random time.
[163421.457398] systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.timer: Adding 42min 47.579987s random time.
[163421.461195] systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 5h 29min 23.008080s random time.
```

And does not show the USB device or any connections at all.

running `adb tcpip 5555` results in `error: no devices/emulators found`.
`adb devices` only lists the Linux host.
`adb reconnect` results in `error: no devices/emulators found`.

Versions are:

- Android NDK r9b
- Android SDK Tools, revision 25.2.5
- Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 29.0.4
- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 29.0.2

Many Stack questions and answers are Windows-specific, requiring different tools than MacOS and Linux. I am wondering if the issue here is that I am attempting to attach the device on a remote machine using a different OS, or if there is another reason I am missing.

Comment: 1. Make sure that your USB port is connected to the VM and not to the host (I don't know which VM you use, but as far as I remember in VMWare you can toggle the port between the VM and the host). 2. Is you cable OK? Have you tried a different one?

Comment: @TDG I'm running a DigitalOcean droplet, so this is all commandline. The cable is fine, but the USB port isn't being recognized by `fdisk -l`. Both ports on my host are working. I've updated my question to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to connect a mobile device to a droplet for debugging as the droplet is only for compiling native binaries. These must be transferred to the host machine via scp, and the debugged through Android Studio.

There might be another way to do this I just don't know what it is,