# “adb devices” returns empty “List of devices attached” on Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, react-native, empty-list, lsusb

Based on react native documentation (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device) I wanted to connect to ADB in my **ubuntu vm (Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS)** but my problem is that i keep getting an empty list.

So what steps I have followed :

1. lsusb to extract mobile model (in my case 2a45)

`devnull@greg_server:~$ lsusb`

> Bus 001 Device 004: ID **2a45**:2008 Meizu Corp. MX Phone (MTP)
>
> Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
>
> Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

2. input this into your udev rules in order to get up and running

`echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2a45", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"' | sudo tee /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android-usb.rules`

3. show adb list

`devnull@greg_server:~$ adb devices`

> List of devices attached

In order to troubleshoot based on

[“List of devices attached” is empty on Ubuntu 16.04 using "adb devices"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46128913/list-of-devices-attached-is-empty-on-ubuntu-16-04-using-adb-devices)

I followed the below steps :

1. created adb_usb.ini file and restarted adb server

`devnull@greg_server:~$ cat ~/.android/adb_usb.ini`

> 0x2a45

`devnull@greg_server:~$ adb kill-server`

`devnull@greg_server:~$ adb start-server;`

> daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
>
> daemon started successfully

`devnull@greg_server:~$ adb devices`

> List of devices attached

2. enabled usb debugging and checked again adb devices

In this case I noticed that lsusb doesn't identify my mobile and adb devices command returns again an empty list as shown below

`devnull@greg_server:~$ lsusb`

> Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
>
> Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

`devnull@greg_server:~$ adb devices`

> List of devices attached

3. checked android usb file configuration

`root@greg_server:/etc/udev/rules.d# pwd`

> /etc/udev/rules.d

`root@greg_server:/etc/udev/rules.d# ls -lst`

> total 64
>
> 4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    71 Oct 24 07:18 51-android-usb.rules
>
> 60 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 58549 May  8 06:28 70-snap.core.rules

`root@greg_server:/etc/udev/rules.d# cat 51-android-usb.rules`

> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2a45", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

Any help on what might be the case?

Comment: Check the authorization in your phone, you should authorize your computer to access your device

Comment: Try also to disable developer options and enable back again. Before you do that also unplug usb from phone. After that enable also usb debugging and you should see "Allow this computer to access ..." dialog.. This should work..

Comment: @mmmatey suggestion did it for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm attempting to get ADB up and running on an older version of ubuntu, but my problems are more fundamental (I'm trying to do this in Virtualbox as well).

However - I noticed that this answer didn't contain something which has fixed the issue for others - the USB configuration mode (a developer option which should be under the dev settings somewhere).

On the device I'm using, this was under "Default USB Configuration" - advice from others appears to be that selecting PTP is the way to go.

Hope that might help out.

Comment: Thanks for your time on this. I will check :)